# Align Rectangle to bottom in ScrollView / GeometryReader view not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, geometryreader

I am trying to get a rectangle to be aligned in a GeometryReader view, that is nested inside a HStack and then ScrollView.

I can not get the Rect() to be aligned to the bottom of the view, it is only drawn from the top.

This does not work, the Rect is drawn coming from the top of View, not from the Bottom of the View.

How do I fix this? I have tried putting the .bottom alignment on all of the views and frames and none of them work.

If additional clarification is needed please let me know.

I updated my code to an actual example.

```
import SwiftUI



struct Scrollview1: View {
    
    
    let samples = [106, 77, 53, 15, 83, 80, 63, 43, 80, 81, 66, 75, 78, 57, 18, 73, 80, 70, 27, 82, 83, 70, 66, 78, 50, 30, 13, 77, 67, 40, 12, 76, 73, 73, 77, 63, 42, 12, 88, 77, 46, 14, 90, 83, 73, 79, 73, 34, 14, 87, 78, 53, 37, 79, 75, 19, 86, 74, 45, 14, 79, 81, 46, 14, 82, 76, 44, 69, 70, 37, 13, 80, 81, 48, 15, 76, 79, 41, 76, 75, 49, 26, 79, 78, 57, 18, 79]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    
            VStack (spacing: 3) {
                
                
                HStack (alignment: .bottom , spacing: 1) {
                    
                    ForEach(samples, id: \.self) { sample in
                        
                        GeometryReader { geo in
                            
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill( geo.frame(in: .global).maxX >  100 && 250 > geo.frame(in: .global).maxX  ? Color.red : Color.gray)
                            //  .frame( alignment: .leading)
                                .frame(width: 5, height: CGFloat(sample))
                            
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
struct Scroll_Previews1: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Scrollview1()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want to reverse the scroll view, as in new items start at the bottom and scroll up. If so, [see this blog post](https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/implementing-reversed-scrolling-behaviour-in-swiftui/). If not what, exactly do you want?

Comment: So I want the Rectangle to be alighted to the bottom of the view. so it is a stalagmite instead of a stalagtight.

Comment: @Yrb I added an image of what it looks like.

Comment: But what else is going in the `ScrollView`? If nothing else, why use it? This would be much easier without the `ScrollView`.

Comment: @Yrb it is a simpliefied example. There are going to be a lot of rectanbles in the scrollview. So if you jut try with one (or more) rectangles you are going to see the issue.

Comment: If you want the second rectangle on top of the first, you are looking to reverse the `ScrollView`, and my first comment gives you a link to resolve it.

Comment: @Yrb, I dont want the second one on top of the first. Please look at the image I posted for what I am looking for. Not sure if I am explaining it correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238558/discussion-between-yrb-and-johnkubik).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. When the `ScrollView` goes into the `GeometryReader` it becomes top aligned with the view. I put a background on the `Scrollview` so you could see it was just a height of 50. Your issue is not the `ScrollView`, it is the `GeometryReader`. The `ScrollView` needs to be in a `VStack` with a `Spacer()` above to push it down.

```
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(0..<30) { index in
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 10, height: CGFloat.random(in: 20...50))
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
        }
        .padding()
    }
```

Comment: I updated my code to show the issue and a picture of what I would LIKE to happen.

Comment: I edited my answer so it causes multiple rectangles.